# how to display data from database in laravel , i stuck in ( $reviews is undefined )

Tags: laravel

Hi Sorry iam new in laravel , iam tring to display data from DB but i get error ($reviews is undefined) in home.blade . Plz help "

web.php :

```
use App\Http\Controllers\ReviewController; 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route; 

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home');
});

Route::get('/car', function () {
    return view('car');
});

Route::post('home',[ReviewController::class, 'reviewstore'])->name('review.store');
```

home.blade :

```
<br/> @foreach ($reviews as $review)
<li>
    {{ $review['name']}}  
</li>
<li>
    {{$review['comment']}} 
</li>
<li>
    {{$review['rating']}} 
</li>
@endforeach
```

ReviewController :

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers; use App\Models\ReviewRating; use Illuminate\Http\Request; class ReviewController extends Controller { public function index(){
    $reviews = ReviewRating::all();
    return view('home', ['reviews' => $reviews]);
}    
public function reviewstore(Request $request){
    $review = new ReviewRating();
    $review->name    = strip_tags($request->input('name'));
    $review->comments = strip_tags($request->input('comment'));
    $review->star_rating = strip_tags($request->input('rating'));
    $review->save();
    return redirect()->back()->with('flash_msg_success','Your review has been submitted Successfully,');
}  }
```

My Model :

```
namespace App\Models; use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory; use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model; class ReviewRating extends Model {use HasFactory;
protected $fillable = [
'id', 
'name', 
'comments', 
'star_rating',
];}
```

Comment: Your code formatting is not good. I have fixed some of this, but there is no sense in making your code harder to read than need be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Route::get('/', function()` code, you don't call the ReviewController index method.

Change it to this and you should be ok

```php
Route::get('/', [ReviewController::class, 'index']);
```

If you want to keep your '/' route definition like it is then add the 'reviews' variable

Documented here.
https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/views#passing-data-to-views

```php
Route::get('/', function () {
    $reviews = ReviewRating::all();

    return view('home', ['reviews' => $reviews]);
});
```

Comment: Thank you i uesed  Route::get('/', [ReviewController::class, 'index']);  and it is worked